# is it possible for an app to know when UILocalNotification happens while in the background?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Is there any way at all for the app to handle a local notification if it's in the background? With application:didReceiveLocalNotification: the app must be in the foreground. Remote notifications have application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: for handling notifications from the background. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

A local notification only wakes up an app that is in the background when the user chooses to enter the app via the alert. Background handlers like for remote notifications are not available. The primary intention of local notification is to act as a reminder for a timer or calendar-event, etc., I'm sure you can solve your problem on another way.